# How to get item's metadata with Entity Framework ? 

Tags: list

I need to know the date of creation/edition and the author/editor of items in my sharepoint's Lists, but I didn't found a solution to map these columns with Entity Framework.

I tried this kind of code :

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name = "tp_author", Storage = "_author", ReadOnly = true, FieldType = "User")]
public SPUser Author
{ 
    get 
    {
        return this._author;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!value.Equals(this._author))
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("Author", this._author);
            this._author = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Author");
        }
    }
}
```

But with that code, Sharepoint give me this error :

> Invalid transfer type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser

I also tried with other types for _author, but it doesn't change anything.

Is there a way to make this mapping ?

Thank you

Baptiste Wicht BlockquoteMicrosoft.SharePoint.SPUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Linq-to-SharePoint, and there is no need in Entity framework.


You need to use **[SPMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538255.aspx)** to generete entity classes that Linq will work with. As I remember by default for columns *creation/edition* and *autor/editor* properties wont be generated in entity class, so you must override default generation rules to include them.


Hope it'll help.

[**Update**]
Here's an example of xml file the will help you  to generete properties for columns:

```
  <List Name="Employee Certifications">
    <ContentType Name="Item" Class="Certification">
        <Column Name="Author" Member="Author" />
        <Column Name="Created" Member="Created" />
    </ContentType>
  </List>
  <ExcludeOtherLists/>
```

By overiding default behavior I was able to create Author and Created property for my entity class, so don't give up and try once more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried that before, but I didn't found any option in SPMetal that help me generate creation/edition and author/editor properties. I tried IncludeHiddenColumns and I also tried to use the exact intrnal name of the column, without success.

Comment: I have updeted answer with example that helped me to generete hidden properties that I nedd, hope i'll help.